# How to move the whole mesh with geometry nodes?

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes

I would like to move the whole instances using geometry nodes. I found the [Transform node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/transform.html), but it doesn't accept a field input (see below).

Is there a way to map a field output (in my case the translation is a function of the position, which is a field attribute) to a socket attribute input, applying the same translation for every point in the mesh?

[[image: error when connecting position to translation 1]

Answer (score 2):

I just found the [Translate instances](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/instances/translate_instances.html) node, which does what I wanted to do in the first place.

However, the general question of "how do I populate the field input all over the whole geometry", aka "how to change from diamond to circle" is still interesting.